# Integral Geometry Reference Request

Tags: reference-request, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-probability, integral-geometry

I am looking for a good introductory reference (book, lecture notes, survey article) on integral geometry. I am especially interested in the [Crofton formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crofton_formula) in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and its extensions to Riemannian manifolds.

So far, I have only had a look at the 2004 edition of Santaló's [integral geometry and geometric probability](http://books.google.at/books?id=xq1iiumncV4C&printsec=frontcover&dq=santalo%202004&hl=de&sa=X&ei=r7m6T_fwEIvxsgb8rJXYBw&ved=0CDYQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false) and Blaschke's "Vorlesungen über Integralgeometrie" from 1955. I find both of them rather inaccessible (for someone not acquainted with the field like me). I also found this [PDF book](http://math.u-bourgogne.fr/IMB/langevin/09_03_introdintegral.pdf) by Rémi Langevin, which happens to be quite meagre on the topics I am interested in.

I am thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Another classics on the subject: Herbert Solomon, *Geometric Probability*, SIAM, 1978.

Comment: Do you know to what extent Solomon treats the Crofton formulae?

Comment: Chapter 5 is titled *Crofton's Theorem and Sylvester's Problem in Two and Three Dimensions* hence my guess is  he does.

Comment: I just had a look at this chapter. I suspect it is about a different theorem by Crofton. Or I completely fail to see the connection...

Comment: Sorry if the reference is misleading, I do not have the book at hand right now. Another reference I heard experts such as Molchanov or Calka mention is *Geometric tomography* by R.J. Gardner (but this one I never did even open hence this is mere hearsay...).

Comment: Gardner does not really treat the "Crofton intersection formulas", as he calls them, but only mentions them in the Notes to Chapter 7. However, he lists some related work in his _huge_ bibliography, so there's a chance that I'll find what I am looking for. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Maybe you can have a look a the really complete book: "Stochastic and integral geometry" from Schneider and Weil.